# What to do when blender crashes when joining two objects together

Tags: modeling

I am creating a locomotive for a game engine and there is are objects I want to join together. So I join 3,  and the 4th crashes Blender. What could cause this? Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: in this kind of case, launch blender using a command line and have a look after the crash if something is written on it.